# Meteor and Polymer run very slow

Tags: javascript, meteor, polymer

I want to use Polymer in an Meteor app for the UI. Therefore I added following packages:

```
ecwyne:polymer           1.0.2  Add Polymer Base to meteor Project

ecwyne:polymer-elements  1.0.3  Add Polymer-Elements to Meteor
```

Loading core-elements seems flawless at first. But when the code gets more complex it starts to run very slow and I get this error in FF33:

```
 mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run  very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial  [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
```

Chrome is slowing down as well.
My code is:

```
<head>
    <title>mali</title>

        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icon-button/core-icon-button.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-card/core-card.html">
</head>

<body>
    <style>    
      #design_host {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      #core_header_panel {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        position: absolute;
      }
      #core_toolbar {
        background-color: rgb(79, 125, 201);
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      }
      #section {
        height: 1000px;
        background: linear-gradient(rgb(214, 227, 231), lightblue) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
      }
      #core_card {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098), 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
        left: 330px;
        top: 186px;
      }

    </style>
    <core-header-panel mode="standard" id="core_header_panel">
      <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar">
        <core-icon-button icon="menu" id="core_icon_button"></core-icon-button>
        <div id="div">MALI</div>
      </core-toolbar>
      <section id="section">
          <core-card id="core_card">

           </core-card>

      </section>
    </core-header-panel>
</body>
```

Comment: Just noticed the same when using core-card, I think core-card is no longer supported. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to too many HTTP requests. The guys at differential.io have created a package that wraps the vulcanize npm package, which is used to process web components into a single output file.

You can give it a go by add the package: differential:vulcanize

```
meteor add differential:vulcanize
```

More info at: https://atmospherejs.com/differential/vulcanize and http://differential.com/blog/meteor-polymer

Hope it helps,

Cheers!